# Is $A$ a vector space in $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let
>   $$A = \{ q + qx : q \text{ is an even integer}\}$$
>   and 
>   $$B = \{ wx + f : w,f \in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
>   Is $A$ a vector space in $B$?

My hints for the question is to 'remember the 10 criteria'

I have the list of 10 criteria that A needs to meet (addition is commutative, 0 exists within A, closed under multiplication, etc).

So I just need to run A through all of those criteria and show whether they work or not?

If they do for all 10, then A is a vector space in B. And if one doesn't work, then A isn't?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú $A$ is a particular **subset** of $B$

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot it’s not a vector space. My bad.